# JBullet RigidBodies

Tags: java, collision, jbullet

I am having trouble implementing collisions with my game, more specifically the main player (once it collides with a box i have setup, it bounces far back). This is the code to setup the viewer:

> ```
>     CollisionShape myCol = new CylinderShape(new javax.vecmath.Vector3f(0.4f, 0.9f, 0.4f));
>     DefaultMotionState motion = new DefaultMotionState(new Transform(new Matrix4f(new Quat4f(0, 0, 0, 1), new javax.vecmath.Vector3f(0, 33, 0), 1f)));
>     javax.vecmath.Vector3f fallInertia = new javax.vecmath.Vector3f(0, 0, 0);
>     //myCol.calculateLocalInertia(0, fallInertia);
>     RigidBodyConstructionInfo cInfo = new RigidBodyConstructionInfo(1, motion, myCol, fallInertia);
>     self_Col = new RigidBody(cInfo);
>     self_Col.setFriction(1f);
>     self_Col.setRestitution(1f);
>     self_Col.setDamping(0.04f, 0.1f);
> ```

And this is the physics world setup:

> ```
>   AxisSweep3 pairCache = new AxisSweep3(new javax.vecmath.Vector3f(-10000, -10000, -10000), new javax.vecmath.Vector3f(10000, 10000, 10000));
>     DefaultCollisionConfiguration collisionConfiguration = new DefaultCollisionConfiguration();
>     CollisionDispatcher dispatcher = new CollisionDispatcher(collisionConfiguration);
>     SequentialImpulseConstraintSolver solver = new SequentialImpulseConstraintSolver();
>     detectionWorld = new DiscreteDynamicsWorld(dispatcher, pairCache, solver, collisionConfiguration);
>     detectionWorld.setGravity(new javax.vecmath.Vector3f(0, -2f, 0));
> ```

I am trying to move the player and then apply the new position to the collision box, and then do a physics step and set the position to the new collision box location. So basically I have two vectors taking in a position.

EDIT: Anyone? I am still having this issue

Answer (score 0):

JBullet often has many of it's units from 0-1. Restitution is what is causing this problem for you, restitution is how bouncy your collision shape is. Your restitution is way to high, try reduce it and see if that helps.

```
self_Col.setRestitution(0.1f);
```